# EJS files are not rendering on Firebase Hosting

Tags: node.js, express, rendering, ejs, firebase-hosting

I have created a project using express.js and EJS, and I am hosting it on Firebase Hosting. However, my EJS files are not rendering nor detected. index.html and 404.html were created by Firebase, and the link to my firebase app is only rendering index.html. I have tried to move the views folder (and home.ejs alone) to the public folder, but it does not work either.

[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/as9jp.jpg)

Project Structure:

[image: project structure]

Firebase App:

[image: firebase app]

Comment: Firebase Hosting is for client side applications and static content / assets, so a node.js app is not going to work. You need something like [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) or [Cloud Run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run) for that.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.